# Display 2D objects over others (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my **platform game**, i have some objects that need to **ALWAYS be displayed on top of the others**, but at the same time need to be **on the same Z axis**.

In my case, this is when i get closer to the "lava", it displays over the other gameobjects:

[image]

And this is when i am farther from it (**and this is how i would like it to stay all the time**):

[image]

If i change the Z axis of the two, of course one would display on top of the other, but because they are 2D they **will not collide with eachother**.

Is any other working way to do this? **Any information or help is really appreciated!**

-

EDIT: just in case, **the ball is the character**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Sorting Layers, which allow you to specify what should be drawn on top of ther things

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html#SortingLayers
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DSorting.html

> ### Sorting Layer and Order in Layer
>
> The Sorting Layer and **Order in Layer** (in the Renderer’s **Property** settings) are available to all 2D Renderers through the Inspector
>   window or via the Unity Scripting API. Set the Renderer to an existing **Sorting Layer** or create a new one to determine its priority in the rendering
>   queue. Change the value of the **Order in Layer** to set the Renderer’s priority among other Renderers within the same **Sorting Layer**.
>
> The **Tags and Layers** settings (main menu: **Edit > Project Settings**
>   , then select the **Tags and Layers** category) allows you to set up Tags
>   , Sorting Layers and Layers
>   .
>   [image: sorting layer]

Comment: Good answer. In the future, be sure to include enough information in the answer itself in case the url breaks or the information otherwise goes missing after the answer is posted. I included some quotes and an illustration from the linked pages that make the answer stand better on its own.